# Changing kivy widget properties for multiple screens from a loop

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a bunch of screens in my app that all have the same icon that I always want to change together. So I currently have it hard coded and everytime I add a new screen I have to add a new line and it's getting cumbersome:

```
self.tcs_screen.ids.statusicon.source = "/imgs/..."
self.eclss_screen.ids.statusicon.source = "/imgs/..."
self.gnc_screen.ids.statusicon.source = "/imgs/..."
...
```

Is it possible to do this from a loop over a list of the screens? I've been trying the following with no success (how do you insert a variable into a property assignment?):

```
ScreenList = ['tcs_screen', 'eclss_screen', 'gnc_screen']
for x in xrange(len(ScreenList)):
        self.ScreenList[x].ids.statusicon.source = "/imgs/..."
```

Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `getattr()` to get the property using the name.

```
screen_list = ['tcs_screen', 'eclss_screen', 'gnc_screen']

for e in screen_list:
    getattr(self, e).ids.statusicon.source = "/imgs/..."
```